# Why does Donald Trump wield influence over Republican Congressmen & Senators?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, congress, republican-party

Given that Donald Trump lost the recent Presidential election, why is it that congressmen [continue to](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/02/18/politics/steve-scalise-donald-trump-mar-a-lago/index.html) [visit Mar-A-Lago](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-55850449)?  In what way is Donald Trump a power broker?  What is it that congressmen seek from Donald Trump?

I realize that this is a forum for politics and that in itself is charged by its very nature.  That being said, the superior answer will posit a plausible hypothesis with references for support.  Questions that seek to clarify the subject matter are appreciated.

Comment: Ridiculously stylized opinion, but related from CNN just this week: [*Donald Trump still runs the GOP, part 8,721*](https://www.cnn.com/2021/07/12/politics/gop-alaska-trump-murkowski-2022/index.html)

Answer (score 100):

It's worth pointing out that Trump is not a 'leader' in the normal, political sense of the term, and his power doesn't lie in typical sociopolitical authority. Trump is (to borrow someone else's analogy) the Golden Idol that a certain segment of American society bows down to. They carry him before them as an icon and cry out that he is their leader, but Trump doesn't do the things we expect of a leader: set paths and agendas, create rules and order, provide structure, clarity, and direction. Trump effectively does nothing except rally his followers: stir them up and incite them to act out on their own (often problematic) impulses. Trump didn't start the movement, or organize it, or define it; he merely 'licensed his brand' to it, giving a diffuse and disorganized movement a banner to rally around. He seemingly has no interest in what they rally *for* so long as they rally *around* him, so he leaves it up to people in the movement to define what the movement is in his name.

All things considered, Trump isn't much different from Q, except that there is a flesh-and-blood person somewhere behind the iconography of Trump (a person we don't know much about, because he consistently hides himself behind media and legal facades), while there is no such specific person behind the iconography of Q (who as far as anyone can tell is [simply made-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QAnon#Identity_of_Q)). But both icons serve the same purpose of being a rallying point around which groups can organize themselves. It doesn't really make sense to ask what power Trump has over the GOP, any more than it makes sense to ask what power any charismatic leader holds. The concept of a 'charismatic leader' is ultimately empty and oxymoronic. A charismatic leader is like a man on horseback who drops the reins and uses the spurs; the horse thinks it's being guided by the rider, the rider enjoys the thrill of charging pell-mell onward, but the rider isn't in control and the horse would behave the same for *anyone* who dropped the reins and used the spurs. It's a symbiotic, almost parasitic relationship.

The power Trump has (to follow this analogy) is merely the power to *trample*: to point his followers at someone and dig in the spurs, and let the sheer weight of all that unconstrained animal energy crush the target. It creates an odd and unhealthy dynamic:

- Some of the GOP leadership want to avoid being trampled, so they play cautiously around Trump out of fear; they try to anticipate what things might tick Trump off and tiptoe around them
- Others in the GOP leadership want to direct that animal energy at targets of their own. Unlike Trump, these leaders have *real* political motivations and machinations — they want to *use* that energy productively; not in the 'raw' way Trump does — and so they actively put themselves in the position of interpreting the word of Trump for followers

This is why people like McCarthy and Graham spend so much time visiting and talking to Trump, while others avoid him and speak about him in hushed tones. The former want to establish themselves as intimates of Trump — in other words, as people who can present themselves as though they speak in *Trump's* voice — while the latter merely want to make it through to their next term without pain and complications.

As to the Trumpist base...I know I've been using a lot of religious ideation here (which shouldn't surprise people who look at the events of the last four years, but probably does), so apologies, but the base grants Trump this 'power to trample' because it wants *salvation*. The Right has been evolving into a 'grievance culture' since (at least) the '80s. It has developed a persistently angry sense of victimization — particularly among white Christian males — because it suffered a string of legal and political setbacks, with an associated implication of guilt and shame. Feminism pointed out the abuses that men have historically leveled against women; the civil rights movement highlighted the abuses whites have visited on blacks; the native American genocide, the failure of Christian theology to stand up against evolution, the comparative economic failure of rural blue-collar workers compared to urban and suburban white-collars, the destruction of the environment by selfish and gluttonous consumption... All this burden of shame was pushed onto the shoulders of a certain conservative segment of American society, but rather than face up to it they sought to negate it: to find someone who could save them from that pressure of guilt and shame. That's what Trump provided.  He told them they were good people; he told them that the bad people were the ones making them feel such guilt; he told them they had nothing to feel shame over, because it was all lies by nasty people and a lying media, but *he* knew the truth and only *he* could save them (make them great again). They bought into it because they *wanted* to buy into it, because *not* buying into it meant they would have to accept the changing face of the US and the load of shame that accompanied it. But they would have bought it from anyone who offered it; Trump just cornered the market first. But like any other faith, once one has bought into the soteriology it is *extremely* difficult to leave, because the salvation of one's entire identity rides on it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120319/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-wrigley-why-does-donald-trump-still-seem-to-have-so).

Comment: I am very torn by this answer.  On the one hand I think many of the insights are relatively accurate, though I feel it would have been better to focus on 'nationalism' then religious analog for your early examples.  However, there are too many biases in phrasing and choice for least appealing analogy when referring to Trump to turn me off due to my inerrant dislike of biased answers (I'm okay with facts, like Qanon was likely 4-6 different people, that can be backed by studies or fact checking, that's different!)  I'd love this answer if some of the clear hatred of trump were reigned in.

Comment: @dsollen: I find this 'hatred' meme fascinating. If you knew me (which you don't), you'd know I'm not given to the emotion 'hatred'. I've been accused at times (fairly) of being coldly, bitterly analytical, but looking over my answer I'm not at all certain what phrases trigger the impression of 'hatred'. I don't respect Trump, and I have a fairly low opinion of his abilities and capacities, but that's all justified empirically by his express behavior and attitude. If he tried harder to be respectable, he'd get more respect. He's not 'due' a d_mned thing from me otherwise...

Comment: @dsollen: To the point: show me what you think is excessive 'hatred' not attributable to Trump's own protracted efforts to make himself disrespectable; I'm open to changing things where I've gone overboard. But if this 'hatred' meme merely means you're don't like that I portray Trump in an unflattering light, well... I'm not really interested in *flattering* anyone or anything. I can probably make my writing more gentle, but I'm not going to make it less evocative.

Comment: @TedWrigley I have no love of Trump either.  I'm perfectly fine with calling out Trump on any clear mistakes he had, on fact checking false information he spread, or even on blantantly clear statements such as "he is argumentative indiviual" because reality shouldn't bend to politics.  However, when there are two equally valid and easy ways to explain a concept and constantly one errs on the side that is more hostile that pushes things to feeling of bias.  That in turn then makes me distrust an answer since I have to question rather it *is* factual, or one is allowing bias to sway their view

Comment: @TedWrigley put simply I feel your basic arguments are correct, though I think the point made about primaries by 'Monica' is also a significant factor.  But If you stuck to more neutral language in situations where there was no need to resort to the more inflaming options it would lead to the answer feeling more trustworthy.  For instance I feel explaining the same the early paragraph(s) by referring to nationalism instead of religious cults would have, if anything, been more applicable while not necessitating analogy to cult leaders that have a clear negative association.

Comment: @dsollen: Let me think about it a bit. It's tricky any way one approaches it. For instance, I considered using mainstream religious icons (Jesus, Buddha, Mohammad) instead of cult leaders, but that comparison would have offended a different (arguably larger) crowd of people. And I've used the 'nationalism' language in previous posts, which called out yet *another* crowd of dissatisfied people, ones nitpicking the definition of nationalism and carping about *reductio ad hitlerum*.

Comment: @dsollen: I'm not sure I can say anything that is perceived as unflattering about Trump (or any beloved public figure) without someone deciding that I'm being hateful and spiteful; that's the nature of this particular beast. But it won't hurt me to reflect on it a bit, and see if I can smooth it out a little.

Comment: This answer could be improved if it pointed out who or what the heck *Q* is.

Comment: @gerrit See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QAnon

Comment: @gerrit: As I mentioned, I don't think Q is anyone. Q is the bizarro-world version of Santa Claus, who goes everywhere, sees everything, and brings psychopathic joy to all the good little conspiracy theorists. With Q it's all about the 'naughty' list, of course, but still... Would it really be useful to add that to the main text?

Comment: @dsollen: I made some revisions; feedback is welcome.

Comment: @TedWrigley Your revisions removed much of the stuff that I felt was unnecessarily argumentative while keeping all the valid observations.  I'm more then happy to upvote the revised answer.

Comment: Some comments: 1) To say that trump didn’t set an agenda seems not supported by evidence: Did he not promise a protectionist America? Did he not promise heavier restrictions on immigration? To try to abolish the individual mandate in health care?Also, he convinced millions of people two times to vote for him and his agenda. I think this is closer to the definition of leader than “to create rules and order”.

Comment: 2) The assertion that he has no interest in what they rally for so long as they rally around him calls for evidence. Do you have evidence of Trump supporting items that were heavily opposed to his agenda just because his constituents supported these items?

Comment: 3) Paragraph 2 is just way too out there for me to comment on it.. 4) Sense of victimization, guilt and shame: do you have polls showing that trump voters/republican voters since the 80s feel particular guilt/shame related to sexual abuse against women, racism, the environment, more than the general population?

Comment: 5) You say that Trump provided a type of redemption regarding supposed guilt around issues, again do you have any polls showing that trump voters voted for Trump because of redemption or something like that, rather than, say, for economic issues, or anti-migrant sentiment or moral issues like abortion? In any case this psychological/political argument should be supported, otherwise it’s just creating a narrative that fits a heavy anti-Trump sentiment. Conservatives create similar narratives about Biden/Obama/Clinton voters. It doesn’t help one understand anything.

Comment: @FoxMulder: X-Files? Really? Well, I guess that makes sense... AAAANYwho... 1) Trump talks, incessantly, but talking and doing are different things. Trump has that habit of certain business people of saying whatever comes into his head and rewarding/punishing people on whether they make it happen, but that's not the same as setting an agenda. Trump barely got anything done (even when he had a sympathetic house and senate) because he =never really worked to organize people. He talks a good game, but that's about it.

Comment: @FoxMulder: 2) 90% of what Trump said during his term (by volume) was self-praise, praise of those who were loyal to him, and attacks on perceived opponents. the remainder was mainly pie-in-the-sky ideas (e.g., "We're going to build the biggest most beautiful wall") that amounted to little more than virtue signaling. His rallies, his speeches, is state of the union were all about him, how great he was, and how great people were for seeing how great he was. How much more evidence do you need?

Comment: @FoxMulder: 3) I'm not interested in what you refuse to think about. 4 & 5) I'm not interested in thoughtless reductionism. enough said...

Comment: @FoxMulder: Conservatives have been making strange and ridiculous stories about Biden, Obama, and Clinton for a long, long time now. Remember birtherism? Bengazi? The email server? Pizzagate? The difference is the conservatives seem to be extremely bad story-tellers, popping out things that are barely credible, catastrophizing things that are hardly noteworthy, and glaringly refusing to provide evidence or substantive reasoning for any of it. What I wrote here is quite credible, fits the observable evidence, and doesn't rely on any patently absurd premises. sorry, but you'll have to deal...

Answer (score 51):

Donald Trump's influence on the Republican Party remains very strong because the vast majority of Republican-leaning voters remain convinced that Donald Trump did not lose the election. (For example, [this report on a post January 6 poll](https://www.newsweek.com/republicans-joe-biden-won-election-legitimately-poll-1562343) had three quarters of Republican leaning voters not thinking Biden had won the election. Poll after poll have shown similar numbers.) Even Mitt Romney, a long-time opponent of Donald Trump, has said that [Donald Trump currently is the presumptive Republican candidate for the 2024 election](https://twitter.com/dealbook/status/1364368036120190977?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1364368036120190977%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.foxnews.com%2Fpolitics%2Fromney-says-trump-likely-republican-nominee-if-he-runs-in-2024).

While Trump did lose the 2020 election, he did manage to get more people to vote for him than has any previous Republican candidate, including himself in the 2016 election. (Trump received 11 million more votes in 2020 than in 2016.) Trump has attracted a huge number of previously disaffected right-leaning voters. That he also has turned off a huge number of previously disaffected left-leaning voters is perhaps irrelevant; those people might not vote in future elections. Trump's apparent ability to make those previously disaffected right-leaning voters be permanent voters is part of what makes people view him as a power broker.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer, but it would be more complete with a note about the primary election system in the US and relevant to the Congress representatives, how many are in a skewed district such that their biggest threat is not the general election but the Republican primary.

Comment: I think that the belief about the election is a symptom, not a cause.  The base believes the election was fraudulent because they are loyal to Trump, not the other way around,  and the party listens to Trump because the base is loyal in him, not because they believe his swill about the election.

Comment: The fact he is still eligible to run again is almost certainly a factor.

Comment: Also, I have the impression that all recently failed incumbents are the next election's presumptive nominee.

Comment: Note that getting more people to vote for him is down to two things: there were of course more eligible voters in 2020 than any previous election, and a higher percentage of those voted than in any Presidential election since 1960.  So by the same logic, he got a lot more people to vote AGAINST him than any previous candidate :-)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voter_turnout_in_United_States_presidential_elections

Comment: @frеdsbend That Mitt Romney would call Trump the "presumptive nominee" says quite a bit. Romney is one of the few Republicans who are not of the opinion that Trump is the best thing since sliced bread.

Comment: [This](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/02/12/a-large-share-of-republicans-want-trump-to-remain-head-of-the-party-cnbc-survey.html) article from CNBC references a poll that shows just 48% of Republicans want Trump to remain at the forefront of the party; 74% want him to be a part in some way which means 26% of the party believes he should remain a part of the party but not its leader. The other 26% don't want him to remain a part of the party. So while Trump remains popular, his influence over the party has lessened by quite a lot.

Comment: @MDevelopment Your "just 48%" is out of context, and even if it's not, that's huge. Jimmy Carter, Michael Dukakis, Bob Dole, Al Gore, John Kerry, Mitt Romney, Hillary Clinton: They were pretty much PNGed (treated as persona non gratis) within their parties after losing the presidential election.

Comment: I believe it's more accurate to say that "the vast majority of Republican-leaning voters *say* that Donald Trump did not lose the election."

Comment: I think this misrepresents Romney's position in this issue a bit. His position that he believes Trump will win a candidacy again in 2024 is a comment regarding what he thinks the Republican base thinks of Trump, not that he supports the idea that Biden didn't win the election. To give credit where it's due, among major Republicans leader, I think he's one of the only ones that has openly and unambiguously said that Trump was defeated in 2020 legitimately and never supported the election fraud narrative. And he's been consistent on that AFAICT.

Comment: @LieRyan I did not mean in any shape or form  to say that Romney has become a Trump sycophant. He always has been and remains an anti-Trumper, even before that phrase was created. Romney is the only Republican senator to vote to convict on impeachment two times. He was merely acknowledging the reality of what the Republican party has become in his statement.

Comment: Re: _"He did manage to get more people to vote for him than has any previous Republican candidate, including himself in the 2016 election"_. It's worth noting that Trump got more votes than **_any_** other candidate received before the 2020 election.  Of course, he still did come in second (both in total vote and electoral vote).

Comment: @Flydog57: But to repeat the obvious, the only reason he got more people voting for him is that there were more total voters and a higher turnout.  He also got more people voting AGAINST him.

Comment: @frеdsbend actually in modern elections the general election nominee of the losing side typically does not run again, at least not for a few cycles, because such races are clear/unambiguous referendums on whether the nation likes the person and their policies, and there's no scapegoats you can reasonably hold up like primary candidates can ("Trump lost, but I, <other candidate>, would have defeated Joe Biden!"), so the parties tend not to elevate such losers to the national spotlight again. Not to mention one would have to be feckless to consider running again so soon at that point.

Comment: Please try to keep your comments relevant to the answer. You keep derailing into topics which were not even mentioned in it.

Comment: @TylerH I don't think any of them feel the election was unambiguous. Not one iota.

Comment: @user253751 Your last comment is a bit difficult to parse, for two reasons: (1) The use of a double negative ("I **don't** think ... **un**ambiguous"), and (2) The use of "them" without a referent. I think I know what you're trying to say, but I'm not sure.

Comment: "Trump has attracted a huge number of previously disaffected right-leaning voters." I think this is probably the most important factor (among many others). At least one major figure has directly stated the opinion that Trump will continue to be a permanent force in the Republican party because he has managed to recruit a large number of previous non-voters into the party. I can't remember who — I think it was Lindsay Graham, in the context of explaining why he went from being anti-Trump to being pro-Trump. I'll try to find the quote.

Answer (score 37):

Primaries, primaries, primaries.

While David's answer is correct, any Trump run in 2024 would also remobilize the never-Trumpers so the overall advantage is uncertain.

However the US POTUS, and Congress, elections require candidates to first get past the hurdle of the most partisan voters of their party, be it Dem or Rep.

Right now, most really, really, committed Republicans back Trump.  Simple as that.  That's what all those "90% still back Trump" polls say, even as, even in places like [Fox News comments - scroll to end, see up/down votes by stance, Jan 5th, 2021](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/joe-biden-was-legitimately-elected-majority-of-georgia-voters-say), his diehard supporters get pushback when they try to spin his election ramblings.

Comes a primary, chances are, unless the Republican party takes a hard stance against, Trump supporters are either going to vote Trump or whoever is backed by Trump.  Anyone not anointed by Trump, from today's political calculus, risks being ousted.  That may change over time, but it is a very real risk today.  More exactly, anyone who gets targeted by one of Trump's infantile "So-and-so is a very bad man. Sad." tweets, or whatever mechanism he'll use to replace it, will get piled on by the faithful.  And Trump is so irascible and over-sensitive that anything can set him off.  Hence all the ring-kissing to avoid getting on his bad side.

As suggested by Fizz, [here's an example of Trump turning against a Republican he didn't like anymore, Jeff Sessions](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/elections/jeff-sessions-tries-overcome-trump-opposition-alabama-senate-runoff-n1233779), his erstwhile Attorney General, who'd lost his favor.  Or [Mark Sanford](https://fortune.com/2018/06/13/trump-twitter-mark-sanford/), who criticized him (and who admittedly had other skeletons in his closet).`*`

A "hard stance against Trump", whether or not some Republicans would like it to happen, risks splitting the party and thus losing to the Dems.  The Republican party seems roughly at 48% and can win, given electoral college and creative redistricting.  It can't if 20% of its voters don't vote or back splinter candidates.  Thus, a principled stance means losing at least one, possibly more, electoral cycles until the Trump voters cool off.

It's happened before.  In 2016, anyone reasonably mainstream in the Rep party got primary-ditched early on and Ted Cruz, [Mr. Abortion-is-wrong-in-case-of-rape](https://www.msnbc.com/rachel-maddow-show/cruz-makes-his-case-against-abortion-rape-exception-msna828011) was last man standing before Trump won.

Lest you see it as a Republican disease, from which the Democrats are immune, look at Sander's foray into the primaries twice, pulling the party leftwards, even as he's not even a Democrat.

**Primaries motivate the uncompromising members of both parties.  Right now,  for Republicans, there is no one more uncompromising than a Trump who has lost.  And his backers.**

The one good thing in all this?  January 6th, 2021 will forever be attack-ad-gold against Trump and his backers.  By Democrats.  By Republicans.

`*` And before you argue that he was just doing the principled thing with regards to Sanford, look how long it took him to ditch [Roy Moore in Alabama](https://www.npr.org/2017/12/04/568274917/removing-any-qualifications-trump-endorses-roy-moore).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120290/discussion-on-answer-by-italian-philosophers-4-monica-why-does-donald-trump-stil).

Comment: +1 A good example would be how Jeff Sessions got primaried and lost to a political outsider backed by Trump, who called Sessions "the biggest mistake of his presidency" (for having him as his GA) and some more obvious insults that I'll omit here https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/elections/jeff-sessions-tries-overcome-trump-opposition-alabama-senate-runoff-n1233779

Answer (score 19):

Putting the answer jamesqf wrote in a comment into words. Trump has so much power over the Republican party because the Republican voter base loves him. Remember, ultimately in a democracy, it is what the voter base votes for that becomes reality. Regardless of whether a politician is currently elected or not, they (in principle) need to do what their voters want. Someone who runs on a pro-college platform for example cannot just switch to anti-college once elected.

(More accurately they can, but their reputations would be ruined and their voter base will not vote for them next time there's an election.)

Note this isn't a bug with democracy, but rather a feature. If the majority of the population is pro-college, then democracy means the country should also be pro-college. It's exactly what democracy should do. An individual politician can resist this temporarily, but they will be voted out, a pro-college politician will be elected, and the country will implement pro-college policies.

Currently, Trump is the most popular choice for Republican voters. [A poll in February 2021 gave him a 54% vote share among Republican voters should a hypothetical 2024 presidential primary election be held now](https://www.usnews.com/news/politics/articles/2021-02-16/trump-regains-support-among-republicans-after-impeachment-poll-finds). Accordingly, he wields soft power over the Republican party, and his endorsement is very lucrative if one's aim is to get elected. This might change someday if the Republican voter base starts supporting someone else, but it's still the case today.

If you are asking why Republican voters continue to support Trump, that's a different question.

Comment: Where the possible "bug" comes in is that right now only about [1/4 of Americans identify as Republican](https://news.gallup.com/poll/15370/party-affiliation.aspx) (same with the Democratic party, but this question isn't about them). 54% support of that is only about 14%. So we have a situation where much substantial legislation can't pass through the US Senate due to the views of a strategic 14% of US voters. I of course say "possible bug" because some people consider inaction a good thing.

Comment: Someone ran a "my opponent is a crook, lock her up" campaign, after being elected immediately changed to "that's not necessary any more", and it didn't really hurt his vote much at the next election.

Comment: @T.E.D. I wonder what percentage of the 3/4 who do not identify as Republican feel the way they do not because Trump turned them away, but rather because they feel Republicans didn't back Trump enough.  Do they not want to call themselves Republican because Republicans are too Trump-like or because Republicans are not Trump-like enough?

Comment: @Ryan_L - Way OT, but one can look at historical trends on that link I provided and make inferences. The highest they ever were since Trump got the nomination in 2016 is 31%, but 25% is right on the lower end of their normal range. Looking back, he actually hasn't seemed to have a very noticeable affect on their party ID. Its more like this is who they've been since mid-Obama, and he just is reflecting that.

Comment: "Someone who runs on a pro-college platform for example cannot just switch to anti-college once elected." Isn't that what Trump did though?  During the campaign Trump claimed he was going to eliminate the federal debt in 10 years or sooner.  It increased by around 50% under Trump.  And it wasn't just after Covid hit.  It went from flat to increasing in his first year of office.  I just don't think you can really explain his presidency as politics as usual.  His base doesn't seem to care what he does or doesn't do.

Comment: @JimmyJames I suppose that indicates that Trump's base don't actually care very much about the fiscal debt. They might care about other things, such as pro-life vs. pro-choice, where Trump's backtracking will make them change their minds (I don't know).

Comment: @Allure Looking at this definition of [cult of personality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult_of_personality): "... of mass media, propaganda, the big lie, spectacle, the arts, patriotism, and government-organized demonstrations and rallies to create an idealized, heroic, and worshipful image of a leader, often through unquestioning flattery and praise.", we can check off a lot of those boxes for Trump's presidency, at least within the GOP and his base.

Comment: @JimmyJames aside from other arguments there is also a difference in switching announced position to doing something opposite to announced position. I'm not into this topic in particular, but I'm pretty certain Trump was a master of both, but the latter (doing something opposite to the announced position) happens often enough in general. Sometimes for good reasons, sometimes less so. Sometimes that is a problem for the person who does it and sometimes it doesn't make enough waves.

Comment: @FrankHopkins I don't disagree completely but I still think that trying to fit Trump's presidency into the standard mold of American politics is misleading.  It's pretty clear that it's unique in a number of ways.  With regard to this particular question, his core base have generally shown strong or enthusiastic support of his positions and actions even if they are completely contradictory to the positions or actions that they just supported enthusiastically, over the course of days.

Comment: @FrankHopkins I think some of this comes down to the fact that Trump's speeches are often almost devoid of meaningful content. They are more impressionistic.  We 'get' what he means.  But I think that might be an illusion to a large degree.  It allows the listener to fill in the missing content with their own ideas.  This is why I think you can have situations where some people are absolutely convinced that said something and other's are completely convinced that he didn't or even said the opposite.

Answer (score 10):

**Because he represents more Anti-Left than supporting traditional Right policies.**

I as a foreigner , have wondered this myself. Trump is very far from traditional right in terms of policies. Conservatism is usually divided into three items. Stability, religious morality, and conservative spending. He spent a lot more than many presidents and wasn't really religious/ morally suited at all and still kept a war going.

**American Election system has allowed for winner takes all and tribalism to take control to quickly judge the opposing side.**

Americans (the left and right) have created religious leaders and this has lead to some odd tribalism . I think this stems from the election process where only popular candidates have been elected and middle agreeably politicians have been thrown away. The problem with this is you get extremes both sides and people will hold to 20% of their values being representative rather than admit they are wrong. This also leads to seeing the other side of having 80% opposing values and grouping people based on poor representation of those values. This is considering most people are probably very middle and there isn't representation for them.

Many Americans are tired of left policies and wanted to retaliate in some way and Trump is the embodiment of fighting the left. Many if were to chose a president which would hold certain values wouldn't vote for trump, but simply voting for Trump is one of spite against the left system.

**I think ultimately people created fear of the opposing tribe and were tired of current policies and Trump was the spite that they wanted to send to the other tribe.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120370/discussion-on-answer-by-luser-why-does-donald-trump-still-seem-to-have-so-much-p). The chatroom allows for more back and forth discussion. Please try to limit comments to suggesting improvements to the answer and use the chat room if you want to discuss the broader subject.

Answer (score 4):

Much is due simply to him wanting to. Any ex-leader could pull the spotlight, but everyone else chooses not to for the good of the party.

Any President is automatically the head of the party. A popular former president still has a great deal of influence as far as endorsements. Even a former candidate such as Hillary Clinton or Mitt Romney matters as someone once chosen to lead the party. Most are aware of this and are careful. Obama didn't endorse anyone (for president). Clinton knew she'd have a strong shot at the 2020 nomination, but might be a weak candidate so early on ruled out a run to let in new blood. Likewise, Biden, as the former VP ("it's Obama's Dad!"), waited 3 extra months to enter the 2020 race after no-one had pulled ahead.

Over to Trump, he flipped parties, mostly Democratic, until 2010, and gladly breaks Reagan's 11th commandment "thou shalt not speak ill of a fellow Republican". What does he care about seeing the Republican party be strong for generations to come, and so on? A normal distinguished former president supports rising stars, and gives them room to grow. Why would he do that? After the Tea Party (and the election of Trump) the Republican party is in a bit of a crisis, making it easier for him to keep attention, but otherwise he's not doing anything that any other ex-leader could do, but doesn't.

Comment: "*Much is due simply to him wanting to.*" I want to have power over Democrats. Doesn't make it so. He had power over them before he was their ex-leader or even their leader. Trump's been a Republican before 2010 as well, at least as early as 1987 when he registered as one.

Comment: @TylerH I'm addressing the narrow Q -- however he did it, he's an ex-president popular with his party. Given that, in Feb. 2021 how does he have influence? I cleaned up the "not a republican"  sentence. FYI he changed party again in 1989.

Answer (score -1):

The answers were not too complicate to pin point. 1) The congressmen, who is interested in running in 2022, will not stay away from a person who can gather/draw both **money and voters**. 2) See response point 1. 3) See response point 1.

While Donald Trump has lost the election, but by no means it was a landslide defeat of him, nor the Republican Party. Actually the Republican has even gained a few seats in the House, while suffer marginal loss in the Senate. This indicates Donald Trump still has huge support from his primary base - the Republican voters, so he remains a formidable political force.

Another reason is his continued fighting for returning. Unlike typical former Presidents, whom have mostly kept a low profile, and stayed away from the general public, but it is not something expected out of Donald Trump. Image what he will do, if FB and Twitter decide to reinstall his account?

So for the better chance of winning, those congressmen must stay close to Mar-A-Logo, the non-official Republican power center. At least till 2022.

Report below at least support part of my response regarding "voters/votes".

> (CNN) A lot of critics of former President Donald Trump want GOP senators to "show some spine." They think the big reason they have
> stayed with Trump through impeachment is because they're scared of
> him. There's good reason to be worried about going against Trump,
> given how popular he is among the Republican base. But I'd argue this
> explanation is at least somewhat incomplete. A lot of GOP senators may
> be willing to vote with Trump because they aren't against him. They,
> like their voters, may really like him and his policies or believe he
> didn't commit an impeachable offense. This theory is probably hard for
> a lot of Trump critics to take, but it does make sense. Trump
> retrospective approval ratings remain in the 80s with Republicans. A
> lot of Republican lawmakers are likely reflected in that high approval
> rating. ...

> Either way, Republican senators realize that Trump
> remains a powerful force within the party. Trump's actually the
> favorite for the 2024 presidential nomination. He is easily leading
> all primary polls. As I previously noted, Trump is in the best
> position of any former one-term president in the polling era looking
> to reclaim his party's presidential nomination. There is little reason
> to believe Trump won't try to take advantage of these numbers. He
> loves the limelight and the adoring crowds. Soon enough, Trump will
> probably be on the campaign trail.

Comment: I think the nay sayer owe this post a clear explanation on his/her negative feeling towards the content. It would be appreciated that any incorrectness in the writing is kindly pointed out. Thanks.

Comment: It wasn't me, but I think I know why. I can see what you were trying to say, and it makes sense and is mostly true (IMO) but the answer itself is somewhat misleading.

Comment: One way to fiix this would be to **(a) add sources**. This is a big one. If you can link to credible sources that can back you up, then you have solved one big issue in your answer.

Comment: Another thing you can do is **(b) elaborate**. Your answer is so short and brief that it doesn't capture the full aspect of the question and hurts what you have written. For example, you should elaborate on the sentence: *Image what he will do, if FB and Twitter decide to reinstall his account?* because it sounds very opinionated and open to interpretation.

Comment: And finally, I would suggest to **(c) broaden your look** -- meaning that you should approach this problem with a more bipartisan look, where you consider all the aspects of this very open-ended question.

Comment: If you can fix these problems (and the several technical issues such as spelling and grammar), you get a +1 from me. ;)

Comment: @Nai45 I do appreciate your comments and suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score -6):

He has influence because the left keeps vilifying him.  As long as they keep bringing him up, he is relevant.  I’d say that at least half of his influence at the moment comes from his second impeachment. It will wain until NY inevitably finds something they can at least spin as a crime from his taxes, that will raise him back into relevancy yet again. Expect the same thing when/if they try to invoke the 14th accusing him of insurrection as some have called for.

In today’s world influence comes from one of two things, money and popularity.  He has money, the attacks on him raise his popularity.  Hell, it’s how he got elected in the first place, the more he survives being attacked, the more popular he becomes.

Comment: I feel like you’re missing some critical point here. He’s powerful because he’s under criminal investigation?

Comment: @divibisan: yes.  Declaring ones political opponents criminals has a long history, and it occasionally backfires.  In this case it gives him legitimacy as a power and opponent of those declaring him a criminal

Comment: This doesn’t explain why GOP Congress members continue to meet with him, and it reads a little like a rant...

Comment: How is "the left" vilifying him any more than those of us who occupy the center?  Or indeed, places somewhat to the right of center?

Comment: @jmoreno: But what if your political opponents actually ARE criminals?  Even apart from acts related to his attempted coup, he certainly seems to have a lot of potentially indictable offenses related to his financial dealings.

Comment: @jamesqf: I explained why he continues to have influence. Innocence and guilt are irrelevant to the dynamic. .

Comment: @ARich: GOP members continue to meet with him because the attacks on him give him influence, to refuse to meet with him gets seen as support of the attacks.  Without the attacks, it’s simply he lost and he’s not relevant, with the attacks, well, if he’s irrelevant why are they attacking him? If he’s relevant, why would you refuse to meet with him unless you are against him.  Uniparty, rino, Lincoln project, the swamp...attacking him validates his position, refusing to treat with him WHILE HE IS BEING ATTACKED, validates his position.

Comment: @jmoreno I really question your premise that "attacks" on him are perpetuating or creating additional influence. You state that the the media attention is raising his popularity. Do you have a source for that claim?

Comment: I'm not sure anyone on the left invited him to CPAC.

Comment: @ARich: His entire shtick has been as the outsider who is fighting against the Establishment. He’s not and never was a leader within the party, he wasn’t a leader on what to do during his presidency, that was McConnell.  He doesn’t have a plan on how to make things better (IMO doesn’t really care about any change), instead he gets his opponents to attack him and then uses that to get his relevancy.  Been doing that since before Cruz “stole” his first election (2016 primary for those with a short memory).

Comment: This is a valid point. The more people try to bury Trump in lawsuits, impeachments, etc etc his supporters don't see him being held to account for his actions, they see an attempt to "cancel" him. It plays directly into his rhetoric and shows his supporters what they're fighting against. The Republicans have created a monster in Trump and I'm not sure they know how to get out of it, so for now they keep playing along.

Comment: Trump's approval ratings, even among Republicans, are worse than ever - he typically enjoyed close to 90% approval among R's throughout his presidency, but his approval rating has dropped by about 10 points since the start of the year. Trump is *less* popular than ever, not more, so the notion that anything has "raised his popularity" is a false premise.

Comment: If you think that ignoring Trump's crimes and spread of disinformation is going to make him less visible to his base, you are most definitely wrong. He's been elevated to essentially a godhead in their eyes. The only people he'd fall off the radar for is everyone else, so that his base would be allowed to grow unchecked by facts, and the law in some/many cases, and would end up being even worse later on. "Silence is the voice of complicity."

Comment: @ewanc so the choices are investigating criminal activity and keeping him relevant via "cancel retaliation" or not investigating criminal activity allowing him to "shoot someone on fifth avenue" and clearly be above the law?

Comment: @Jontia that certainly seems to be the position he's trying to put himself in. Any criticism can only be coming from "never-trumpers" and "fake news media", therefore if somebody suggests that he has done anything wrong it must be an unfounded political attack, which in his supporters eyes reflect badly on the people investigating and make trump look better because of "all the things he achieved despite the attacks". I'm not saying I agree with it, or that it will win him new friends, just that his die hard base will see this as more reason to support him.

Comment: @ewanc I don't think it matters how much criticism he gets, since he can always act like  he's getting attacked unduly. Certainly stopping criticising him will not stop him using the "under attack unfairly" rhetoric.